# Youtrack Query : how to get issues where story point field was updated

Tags: youtrack, youtrack-api

I'd like to get all issues with a specific tag updated date with YouTrack Query, but I can't find a way to do this in the official doc : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Search-and-Command-Attributes.html#relative-date-parameters

For example, I'd like to get all the issues where the field "story point" has been updated during the last 2 days

I know how to set range with `updated : {last 2d} .. *` 
but not how to look for specific tag :(

Is there any way to get this result ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you looking for issue tags or for specific issue custom field values? These are different entities in YouTrack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it won't be possible to find issues where only a specific custom field value was updated in the last two days.
You can only find issues that were last updated in the last two days if you use a search query like `updated: 2022-05-03 .. *`. The `updated` value of an issue doesn't specify which update it was, it could be any update.

If you want to track changes in a specific issue custom field, I'd suggest creating a special custom field and a custom workflow for that. You can store the timestamp of the update of a particular custom field in that special field via custom workflow. Then, you'll be able to search for issues with specific values of that special custom field.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer ! 
The custom workflow to fill a custom field created for an already existing info on the issue seems to be overkill for my needs, I will filter with `updated` and check the issue by hand...